# Google drive is creating duplicates on the cloud

Tags: google-drive

We are a company of about 43 users, spread all over the country and we not only get duplicates on our local drive, but on the Google drive itself. So a directory might contain a few hundred files that we have to go through one by one and compare which is larger, which is newer.

The Google driver version is 1.25.0523.2491.  We are using Macs and PCs. Mine personally is on automatic sync.  I believe it is that way for the 4 people in my office and a few satellites.

Please say there is a resolution because the president of our company is really angry that we keep having these problems.

Comment: Are the duplicated docs all files created and synced from Mac and PC, or are some of them Google Docs and Sheets? Does the problem only happen when people edit these files in particular programs, e.g. MS Word? Surely the problem can be debugged and fixed, but anger is not a healthy attitude.